# How to round up a number in Python including 0

Tags: python

How to round up a number to two decimal places including
For example, 1.599 should be rounded up 1.60 and not 1.6

Comment: 1.60 is the same as 1.6. Are you asking about the formatting when you print the value?

Comment: you can round this way only when you convert number to string .

Comment: @furas: And what about `round(1.599, 2)`?

Comment: @Matthias I know 1.6 is the same as 1.60 but OP ask about 1.60 and not 1.6

Comment: @furas: In that case "round" is the wrong word. It's about "formatting".

Comment: @Matthias that's right. But beginners sometimes don't know what word to use to describe problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You may do it using string formatting with `%f` as:

```
>>> '%.2f' % 1.599
'1.60'
```

OR, using `str.format()` as:

```
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(1.599)
'1.60'
```

Note: This value will be of `str` type. If you will type-cast it to `float`, you will loose the trailing 0s

Answer (score 1):

Use `%` or `str.format()` to convert the number to a string, formatting it in the process:

```
"%.2f" % 1.599
"{:.2f}".format(1.599)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous from the question if rounding "up" or just rounding is meant. If the first is implied then one can do:

```
import math
x = 1.599
x = math.ceil(x*100)/100
"%.2f" % x
```

Comment: @hakeen: round part is handled by `"%.2f" % x"`. If you are specific about handling it keeping the data type as `float`, `round()` is better choice as `ceil` returns the ceil value not the rounded value

Comment: He specifically asked for rounding "up".

Comment: Techinacally yes. But as an idiom it means "collecting it together". I do not think OP is talking about the `ceil` or may be he is. It is ambiguous here.

Comment: So why do I deserve a negative on my answer for literally answering his question?